# How does if statements in apply affect runtime

Tags: r, apply

If i have a condition, does putting it inside/outside an apply function affect run time significantly for example:

```
names = c("Joe", "Jen", "Bob")

if("Joe" %in% names){
     lapply(1:1000000, function(y){
        #Do something computationally intensive
     })
}
if("Jen" %in% names){
    lapply(1:1000000, function(y){
        #Do something computationally intensive
    })
}
```

Versus:

```
lapply(1:1000000, function(y){
    if("Joe" %in% names){
        #Do something computationally intensive
    }
    if("Jen" %in% names){
        #Do something computationally intensive
    }
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` in the loop is very expensive.

Use rbenchmark to see.  Writing the first as function 'a', the second as 'b', gives this:

```
> benchmark(a(), b(), replications=1)
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  a()            1   0.595     1.00     0.593    0.000          0         0
2  b()            1   4.141     6.96     4.121    0.001          0         0
```

Suggested to put both "Joe" and "Jen" into names.  The results are about the same.

```
> benchmark(a(), b(), replications=1)
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  a()            1   0.600    1.000     0.597        0          0         0
2  b()            1   4.036    6.727     4.016        0          0         0
```

EDIT:  Note that the expressions that you give to `benchmark` are evaluated inside the timing loop, and thus function parentheses must be supplied.

Comment: What about if both are in `names` ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have made the examples so that they are both in names. You wouldn't expect to see much of a difference if it's just one case

Comment: Oddly enough, the results are essentially the same.

Comment: Hmm, yes indeed. I just tested it. I always thought having an if statement inside the apply function would prolong the running time. Guess not